# Type delegation in Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, inheritance, karma-runner

I have the following scenario (code snippets, some code left out for brevity):

```js
export class ValidationBuilderBase implements IValidationBuilder {
    public isRequired(): IValidationBuilder {
        const validationResult = Validators.required(this.baseControl);

        if ((!isNullOrUndefined(validationResult) && !isNullOrUndefined(validationResult.required))) {
            this.baseErrors['required'] = 'This input is required.'; // a ValdationErrors instance
        }

        return this;
    }
}

export interface IValidationBuilder {
    isRequired(): IValidationBuilder;
}

export class StringValidationBuilder implements IValidationBuilder {
    constructor(private readonly builder: Validationbuilderbase) {}

    isRequired(): StringValidationBuilder {
        return this.builder.isRequired() as StringValidationBuilder;
    }
}

// other code, this is in the function
let builder = new ValidationBuilder(this.formGroup.controls['test']);
let validator: StringValidationBuilder = new StringValidationBuilder(builder);
const result = validator.isRequired(); // what should this type be? StringValidationBuilder or IValidationBuilder?
```

Where I am using the builder pattern to execute some code, and return an instance of itself. However, while running the code (through karma jasmine test) in the developer tools, `validator.isRequired()` resolves in a type `IValidationBuilder`.

I am expecting it to result in `StringValidationBuilder`, as `StringValidationBuilder` is implementing the interface, but overriding the return type with `StringValidationBuilder`, which should be valid?

I am confused. In the IDE (VsCode) the code completion states that the return type should be `StringValidationBuilder`

**Edit**

I am trying to achieve the following:

```js
describe(`String validation chaining`, () => {
    it(`should return no errors from the (valid) chain`, () => {
        control().setValidators(Validators.required);
        control().setValue('This is some test string......');
        const result = validator
            .string
            .ifTrue((val) => false, 'error', 'should not reach here')
            .ifFalse((val) => true, 'error', 'should not reach here')
            .isRequired()
            .maxLengthAllowed(100)
            .minLengthAllowed(0)
            .range(25, 35)
            .build();

        expect(result).toEqual(null);
    });
});
```

I got it working by modifying the code to

```js
export class StringValidationBuilder implements IValidationBuilder {
    isRequired(): StringValidationBuilder {
        this.builder.isRequired();

        return this;
    }
}
```

I'm still not convinced this is the ideal solution.

Comment: try changing `isRequired(): IValidationBuilder` to `isRequired(): this`. don't change the return type in derived classes. Keep using `:this`. I honestly can't remember if this is a TypeScript thing or if I'm confusing this with another language.

Answer (score 2):

How can it ever be `StringValidationBuilder`, you are returning a `ValidationBuilderBase`, because that's what the builder is. And the StringValidationBuilder is not extending it

I believe what you are trying to do, is to to make the `StringValidationBuilder` extend the `ValidationBuilderBase`. You can make your life a lot easier by just using the `super` call:

```
export class ValidationBuilderBase implements IValidationBuilder {
    constructor(private controls: any) {}

    public isRequired(): ValidationBuilderBase {
        return this;
    }
}

export interface IValidationBuilder {
    isRequired(): IValidationBuilder;
}

export class StringValidationBuilder extends ValidationBuilderBase {
    constructor(controls: any) {
        super(controls);
    }

    isRequired(): StringValidationBuilder {
      return super.isRequired();
    }
}

const validator = new StringValidationBuilder(this.formGroup.controls['test']);
const result = validator.isRequired();

// result is now a StringValidationBuilder
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=24&ssc=39&pln=1&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwDYEMDOa4DUVIJYAmKMeEAdgEICueSBwUF6wceAtmEsG8GTJgEkc+IiXLVa9KHADeAKDiLE5NDChUEMaAAowUPADdiLBOTUQkaAFxwUZAJ4BKWQF85CpWCoAjfAlZoAErAAI40UMAE2o42woTEpJQ0dAxMaCzySllwETBUUGRwMAAWeGgA3B6Kbm5yoJCwrHwMAGYoCCxCuPFiSZIMslUBwWF4EVExcF0iCeLJUpW19dDwyOiYAMpqeGQA5nGiiRIp0qAwvASYB7N9J2kZQ6ZkquqaOk-mljZ2ToPZSmgqGAGNoPlALGhHJUsrUsmURuFItEbFt9Htrr1jlI-tlcvlCoDgVAAHTw0KIibQpQ1dxceBGGZaaQAXjgZGAAHc4Kidvtuoc5v0oNoSmViS1oGwAOLgoHEsEQgDaAHJzqplQBdKFyJ6qHLAQFIeCshk9aCkoLksZIqFAA)

Comment: I think OP's intention is to create an api with fluent interface. So he wants to chain validation rules like this : `validator.isRequired().maxLength(6).pattern('Regex');...`

Comment: @Eldar right, I figured something like that. The brevity of the code doesn't make that clear. But for that, he still does not need to pass along a separate builder in the constructor, right?

Comment: I do see the problem, @PierreDuc you are right. I am trying to create a fluentApi as Eldar said, but I am not returning the correct types. 

I also think you are right, I should also extend the base, but in the mean time I did the edited section which results in me doing what I needed.

Comment: There are reasons I cannot extend the ValidatorBase, which I'll not delve into here. That is why I have to create an instance of the builder with a base builder, that is passed around and doesn't lose reference. I use it like `const validator = new ValidationBuilder(formControl).string.range(lowerRange, upperRange);`, where the `.string` is the correct builder to be used (`StringValidationBuilder`). We have a bunch of other validators, 'string' was just the easiest to use here. broken up to make the builders responsible for their own validations.